# How to remove excess border in :active state? tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I currently have a weird problem using tailwindcss. The button below looks fine.

[image]

But when I click it does shape pill/rounded, instead its a rectangle below.

[image]

Someone knows how to make the active state shape same as the current one?

---

Here is my button code:

```
<button class="flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none rounded-3xl 
bg-green-200 text-gray-800 text-13 h-8 px-3">
  Goto Button
</button>
```

I tried to add below code. But doesn't work

```
active:rounded-3xl
```

Device tested: iPhone X (using chrome browser (CTRL+SHFT+M))

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks more like the button is being highlighted like when you drag your cursor along text.

Comment: @NathanDawson it highlights when I hold click. I think i did not drag

Comment: I put your code into Tailwind Play (https://play.tailwindcss.com/) and couldn't replicate it.

Comment: @NathanDawson the rectangle blue appears if I hold click the button. Using chrome device - iPhone X (CTRL+SHFT+M). I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two possible solutions

**1)** This could be fix by disabling the [preflight of tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight) but unfortunately it can cause major design problems for possible affected pages.

```
corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
}
```

**2)** Alternatively this could be solve by changing the cursor style. Add this class to the button `cursor-auto`.

```
<button class="cursor-auto flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none rounded-3xl 
bg-green-200 text-gray-800 text-13 h-8 px-3">
  Goto Button
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, `active` variant is not enabled for most of the plugins.

You need to add a small config change in `tailwind.config.js`

Extend the `borderRadius` plugin

```
//Add this change in tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      borderRadius: ['active'],
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**
By default, only some variants like `focus`, `hover` etc are enabled for the plugins(core-plugins only)

For more info, refer to
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

For borderRadius,
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius

Comment: already tried this one before the marked answer. but it doesn't work. maybe you could test it also in tailwindcss-playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/